# Accessing binding expression values in Python Azure Function

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

Is it possible to access the values of `function.json` binding expressions from within a Python Azure function?

This is what I want to do:

`function.json`:

```
{
    "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
    "disabled": false,
    "bindings": [
        {
            "name": "myblob",
            "type": "blobTrigger",
            "direction": "in",
            "path": "samples-workitems/{folder1}/{folder2}/",
            "connection":"MyStorageAccountAppSetting"
        }
    ]
}
```

`__init__.py`:

```
import logging
import azure.functions as func


def main(myblob: func.InputStream):
    logging.info('Python blob folder 1: %s', myblob.folder1)
    logging.info('Python blob folder 2: %s', myblob.folder2)
```

[This Example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-trigger?tabs=python#example) makes it look like it should work, but in reality it seems like the `name` variable is hard coded.

Answer (score -2):

To use the return value of a function as the value of an output binding, the `name` property of the binding should be set to `$return` in `function.json`.

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "req",
      "direction": "in",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "authLevel": "anonymous"
    },
    {
      "name": "msg",
      "direction": "out",
      "type": "queue",
      "queueName": "outqueue",
      "connection": "AzureWebJobsStorage"
    },
    {
      "name": "$return",
      "direction": "out",
      "type": "http"
    }
  ]
}
```

For further information check [Binding expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python?tabs=azurecli-linux,application-level#outputs)

Comment: Thank you, but I'm not asking about the return value of the Python function. Rather, I'm trying to use values from the `function.json` binding expressions as *inputs* to the Python function.